# How to execute the Environment Variables (env.) from Teamcity in Nant script

Tags: teamcity, nant

I am using TeamCity to build the.Net Solution using Nant script and everything works fine if I hard Code the solution path. I want to use  Environment Variables from TeamCity (env.) to be used as Solution Path -->env.solution.path----- C:\a\testteamcity\Demo\deptest.sln inside Nant script  test.build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name ="first Nant file"  default="compile-solution" >
<property name="bin.folder.svn" value="C:\a\testteamcity\Demo\bin123"/>
<property name="bin.folder.sln" value="C:\cicheckout\webapp\bin"/>

<target name="compile-solution">  
   <exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\Msbuild.exe"   verbose="true" >
      <arg line="${environment::get-variable('env.solution.path')}" />
      <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release" />
   </exec>

<copy todir="${bin.folder.sln}" overwrite="true" failonerror="true">
        <fileset basedir="${bin.folder.svn}">          
        </fileset>
</copy>
</target>
</project>
```

Error:Unexpected token 'Punctuation'.
Expression: ${environment::get-variable(‘env.solution.path’)}
Any Help would be great.Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's probably as simple as the quotes you've used, unless that's just a copy paste error - your `get-variable` parameter should just be surrounded with simple single quotes: `${environment::get-variable('env.solution.path')}`

Comment: That is just copy paste error : [15:59:54][NAnt output] Expression: ${environment::get-variable('env.solution.path')}
[15:59:54][NAnt output]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[15:59:54][NAnt output]     Environment variable "env.solution.path" does not exist.

Comment: Note that you've now got a different error.

Comment: Hi, James, I tried with different quotes but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Create system.solution.path --> C:\a\testteamcity\demo\deptest.sln under System Properties (system.) in Teamcity and in Nant script-->

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name ="Build-Solution"  default="build-solution" >
<property name="solution.path" value="${system.solution.path}"  dynamic="true" unless="${property::exists('solution.path')}"/>
   <!-- Build solution  -->
 <target name="build-solution">  
<exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\Msbuild.exe" verbose="true" >
    <arg line="${solution.path}" /> 
    <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release" />
</exec>
</target>
</project>
```